# Buck-Boost power supply I_ripple calculation

Tags: power-supply, buck, boost, ripple-current

I'm not looking to get torn apart, just looking for a hand.

I can't remember exactly how to calculate the RMS Current required from the output capacitors or a Buck-Boost power supply and I was hoping to get some help. If someone could show me how its done that would be awesome but equations will help as well. I have listed some specs below if anyone wanted to try doing some quick math out, I can post more if needed as well.

I chose the following Inductor and for now I chose to use 4 of the following Capacitors just in my preliminary design, I will change/add/subtract them depending on the calculations. I just need to know what the bulk capacitors will have to supply for current @100kHz, the other caps are just for fine tuning later on.(Inductor Selected: IHLP3232DZER2R2M01, Capacitors Selected: TCJD476M020R0055)

Iout(MAX) = 5A,
Vout = 13.6V,
Vripple = ±.1V,
Cout(4@47uF) = 188uF,
CAP_ESR(@100kHz) = 55mΩ,
CAP_DF(MAX) = 6,
Fsw = 100kHz,
Vin(MIN) = 4V,
Vin(MAX) = 20V

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're talking about a non-inverting buck-boost, so for the output caps the boost mode is the worst case.

So using the minimum input voltage and maximum output current follow the steps given [HERE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60950/how-does-one-compute-the-ripple-currents-seen-by-a-boost-converter-output-capaci) to calculate the ripple current in the capacitors.

You can also download a power stage calculator that can do the calculations for you like the following one from TI: [Power Stage Designer](http://www.ti.com/tool/powerstage-designer?keyMatch=power%20stage%20designer%20tool&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything)