# Capacitor loss in high frequency DC-DC converter

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, boost, loss

I have designed a boost converter:

Vin = 60 V

Vout = 150 V

Switching frequecny: 340 kHz or maybe higher

Filter capacitor: 1uF

The picture is only a basic structure of boost converter, and what I mean is the output capacitor C.

[image]

Now I'm calculating the losses in the circuit. I know that the capacitor loss should not be high in my circuit and the ESR should be low enough to ignore. However, I still want to know how to calculated the filter capacitor loss. All files I have found basically all related to Rc which I dont know how to get.

Q: The calculation method or thoughts about how to calculated the filter capacitor loss.

Comment: No circuit usually means no help and this question isn't an exception.

Comment: A boost convertor usually has a cap on the input and one on the output .The output cap works harder .Which cap do you mean?

Comment: The output cap:)

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the RMS ripple current in the output capacitor, see [THIS question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302976/buck-boost-power-supply-i-ripple-calculation/302992#302992), then multiply the RMS ripple current by the ESR of the capacitor and that gives you an estimate of the losses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About the ESR, how can I define the value of it? From the datasheet (did not see that parameter in the datasheet of the capacitor I use) or measure or estimate?

Comment: Does the datasheet give the dissipation factor?  If so you can calculate the ESR with DF=ESR/Xc, where DF is the dissipation factor, and Xc is the capacitive reactance at the specified measurement frequency.  Measuring ESR accurately is difficult and requires specialized equipment.  (Your test leads for example probably have more resistance than a ceramic cap would.) If you have a good LCR bridge or a network analyzer you may be able to do it.  Alternately find another capacitor that does specify the ESR.